# Changing Regular Expression in all Python Scripts in a Directory

Tags: python, regex

```
#current file is named change_directory.py
import csv
import os, os.path
dir = "C:\blahblahb\Released Database\August 2013\blerblerbler/"
for root, _, files in os.walk(dir):
  for f in files:
    if f[-2:] == "py" and f[:6] !+ "change":
      with open(directory + f, "rb") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        for row in reader:
          for item in row:
            if item[:9] == "statement":
              item = item[:52] + "Released Database/August 2013 Release" + item[67:]
            print(item)
```

The problem I'm having is that when I update my database version, I have to continuously change the names of the new directories, so my scripts that point to old folders have to be updated.  I wanted to automate the changing of the directory locations.  I've been able to effectively produce the corrected string that I want the "item" variable to have.  The issue though is that I want to change the corresponding string in a Python (.py) file, and not a csv, and I'm not clear how to do this.  I'm essentially just trying to do a "find" and "replace" for a particular string in hundreds of ".py" files, but I'm having trouble writing out the final output...I would greatly appreciate any help!

For example, I want the script to take change the following lines in all my scripts in the directory:

```
  statement = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/blahblahb/July 1/Database Update/unique_file_name.csv'
```

to say:

```
  statement = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/blahblahb/Released Database/August 2013 Release/Database Update/unique_file_name.csv'
```

Comment: Hello. Are your files very big or not ? By 'big', I mean that they can't be loaded in memory. If they are not big, the files can be read (= put in RAM) and the content can be analyzed with regexes.

Comment: In your code, I doubt that ``for item in row:`` ``if condition...:`` ``item = new_object`` does really change the content of the row. What does this snippet is that identifier ``item`` is moved from its initial object to a new object, but while this is done, the list remains referencing the same objects as elements of itself.

Comment: Thanks...the files range from 1-10 kilobytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, you should store that string in a global configuration file or database field and refer to it across your files.